# Degree and Basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I'm trying to express the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[4]{3})$ as a simple extension over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that $\left[ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q} \right] =2 $ and $\left[ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[4]{3}):\mathbb{Q} \right] =4 $. My intuition tells me that $\left[ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[4]{3}):\mathbb{Q} \right] =8 $, however when I work out basis, it seems like it should be 4. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ because $\sqrt{3}$ is already in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$, as you've noticed. (This expresses the field as a simple extension over $\mathbb{Q}$.) Thus, the correct degree is indeed $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$$
with an easy choice of basis being $\{1,\sqrt[4]{3},(\sqrt[4]{3})^2,(\sqrt[4]{3})^3\}$.

Comment: Thank you. Before the edit was made I was going to ask if the basis I received was correct. So why does the theorem that states $\left[ K:F \right]=\left[ K:E \right] \cdot \left[ E:F \right]$ not hold in this case? Or did I use the theorem incorrectly?

Comment: The theorem does hold. With $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{3})$, $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$, and $F=\mathbb{Q}$, we get
$$[K:F]=4,\quad [K:E]=1,\quad [E:F]=4$$
and with instead $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, we get
$$[K:F]=4,\quad [K:E]=2,\quad [E:F]=2$$

Comment: Keep in mind, I am claiming that the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ are identical, so everything that's true stays true no matter which way of writing it you choose.

Comment: Okay, so how would you prove they are identical? Just that $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$?

Comment: Yes. Of course in most cases the task of expressing a number field as a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is not quite as easy, but here it really is. Remember, if $L/K$ is any extension of fields and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m\in L$, then the field
$$K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_m)=\text{the smallest subfield of $L$ that contains both $K$ and the $\alpha_i$'s}$$
Any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt[4]{3}$ must already contain $\sqrt{3}=(\sqrt[4]{3})^2$, so requiring separately that $\sqrt{3}$ be present is redundant.